# node.js as front end authentication for cloudfront + s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm a fan of using cloudfront + s3 to serve static sites.  I have a use case where I need to run a site in s3, but I need authentication.  I'd like to be able to handle this in a serverless way, but I need some sort of application to handle the auth logic.

My idea is that I could run a node.js application on something like elastic beanstalk in front of cloudfront to handle authentication.

Basically a user makes a request to the application, my app authenticates the user with our authentication backend, creates a cookie returns it and then serves the private cloudfront url for the requested resource.  Am I on the right track here?

The idea is to have a gated s3 website that a user can browser after authenticating.  I think this could be achieved using node http and passport to authenticate and then use the aws sdk to create the signed cookie.

Comment: What is your actual question? Please keep in mind that broad question that invite opinionated discussion are off-topic for Stack Overflow (see [ask])

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This makes sense.

Depending on your use case, it might be sufficient to use AWS API Gateway + Lambda for login page and authentication (instead of elastic beanstalk).

Also AWS recently announced Lambda@Edge which is a way to execute Lambda functions in response to Cloudfront events. That could work for what you are describing - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-response-generation.html

Comment: Cool cool. I think that Lambda edge doesn't allow external network calls, but Lambda + api gateway could probably fit the bill.